# macvim - "Missing" vimrc still in use by vim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I've been using macvim for a long time now, but i've recently come across a rather big problem - i don't have a .vimrc, .gvimrc, or anything similar anymore. The files are just gone from my system. However, macvim is still using all of my old settings and plugins, and if i try to create a new .vimrc in the appropriate place (ie. the path pointed to when i type :version), the old missing ("rogue" would perhaps be a better term...) vimrc is still used. In other words, i have no way to change my vim settings. I would prefer not to reinstall as i like the way i've set up vim so i'd rather find my missing file.

Has anyone had this problem? Running on El Capitan

Comment: Try, in **Terminal** `find  $HOME  /  -iname  ".*vimrc"`

Comment: The `:scriptnames` command should tell you which initialization (and plugin) files have been read by the current Vim session.